# PyPDF2 error "PyCryptodome is required for AES algorithm"

Tags: python, pypdf, pikepdf

I've got hundreds on PDFs I need to set password. I tried to use pyPDF2 to do that but I got an error:
"DependencyError: PyCryptodome is required for AES algorithm".

I've tried to google any other module like pikepdf but I found only how to crack the password using it and not to actually set password.

Any ideas how to deal with it? I get an error on that line: "**input_pdf = PdfFileReader(in_file)**"

```
file = directory + '\\passwords.xlsx'  

df = pd.read_excel(file)
df['PDF'] = df.iloc[:,[0]] + '.pdf'

df = df.to_dict('records')
for i in df:
    filename = i['PDF']
    password = i['Password']

    with open(filename, "rb") as in_file:
        input_pdf = PdfFileReader(in_file)

    output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()
    output_pdf.appendPagesFromReader(input_pdf)
    output_pdf.encrypt(password)

    with open(filename, "wb") as out_file:
        output_pdf.write(out_file)
```

Comment: I'd start with [installing PyCryptodome](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I do have pycryptodome installed. 

I get an error here: 
with open(filename, "rb") as in_file:
     input_pdf = PdfFileReader(in_file)

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem.

You just need to install `PyCryptodome` package.

For example:

```
pip install pycryptodome==3.15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

## A.) Great way to do it:

https://roytuts.com/how-to-encrypt-pdf-as-password-protected-file-in-python/

```
import PyPDF2

#pdf_in_file = open("simple.pdf",'rb')
pdf_in_file = open("gre_research_validity_data.pdf",'rb')

inputpdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_in_file)
pages_no = inputpdf.numPages
output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

for i in range(pages_no):
    inputpdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_in_file)
    
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    output.encrypt('password')

    #with open("simple_password_protected.pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
    with open("gre_research_validity_data_password_protected.pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)

pdf_in_file.close()
```

## B.) If you want to fix your own bug:

solution for similar error message but during counting pages - [Not able to find number of pages of PDF using Python 3.X: DependencyError: PyCryptodome is required for AES algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73533948/)

ORIGINAL CODE

```
! pip install PyPDF2
! pip install pycryptodome
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

if PdfFileReader('Media Downloaded Files/spk-10-3144 bro.pdf').isEncrypted:
    print('This file is encrypted.')
else:
    print(PdfFileReader('Media Downloaded Files/spk-10-3144-bro.pdf').numPages)
```

FIX

```
! pip install pikepdf 
from pikepdf import Pdf  
pdf = Pdf.open('Media Downloaded Files/spk-10-3144-bro.pdf') 
len(pdf.pages)
```

Comment: I get the same error using this code. 

If I hardcode name of pdf it works as supposed to. Problem occurs in some reasons while looping over excel file read by pandas :/

Comment: @rammbb I have updated my answer B.) ```! pip install pikepdf```

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. I don't want to read it but SET a password.

Comment: @rammbb yep but the password settings seems all right, but as you mention the reading causes the error.